# How to read a metadata file efficiently?

Tags: java, metadata

My current project is using a metadata file to set properties without having to compile. Currently I have it set up in this way:

```
metadata.txt
[property] value <br/>
[property2] value2

File f = new File("metadata.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
String variable1 = "";
String variable2 = "";
```

Now read this file using a BufferedReader and getting the information in a certain order. Such as:

```
variable1 = in.readLine();
variable2 = in.readLine();
```

I was wondering is there a better way to do this without having to read line by line? I was trying to think of using a loop but I'm not sure how that would work out since I want to set different String variables to each property.

Also I'm not using a GUI in this program so that is the reason why I'm editing the data raw.

Comment: Alright so all 3 of you left the same answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather use the [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API. It's designed exactly for this purpose.

Create a `filename.properties` file with key=value entries separated by newlines:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

Put the file in the classpath (or add its path to the classpath) and load it as follows:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
```

Then you can obtain values by key as follows:

```
String key1 = properties.getProperty("key1"); // returns value1
```

#### See also:

- [Properties tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an answer to this question.

You can use `java.util.Properties` and its methods to save or load properties from the file. You metadata file looks like a property file, if you don't target doing something special.